# $C \subset [0,1]$ is Cantor set, suppose $f(x):\Bbb{R}^1\to[0,1] $ is onto and measurable. Does $f^{-1}(C)$ measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

> $C \subset [0,1]$ is the Cantor set, suppose $f(x):\Bbb{R}^1\to[0,1] $ is onto and measurable. Does $f^{-1}(C)$ measurable.

I tend to think it is measurable since  $m(C)=0$ but incapable to make a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 2):

$C$ is a closed, hence a Borel set. If $f$ is measurable then $f^{-1}(C)$ is measurable.

Comment: I can understand $C$ is a Borel set , but really hard to know $f^{-1}(C)$ is measurable.

Comment: @LOIS What is your definition of a measurable function?

Comment: for any $a\in \Bbb{R}$. $E\{f\gt a\}$ is measurable.

Comment: With that definition you can show that inverse image of any Borel set is measurable. This is a standard result found in any book on measure theory. In particular you can look at Rudin's book.